# Why does this use of Socket.setSoTimeout() not work?

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

This code snippet is from a TCP helper function I made in Android java:

```
            socket.setSoTimeout(2000);
            InputStream inStream = socket.getInputStream();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
            true);

            out.println(message);

            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));

            String tcpResult = "";

            if(lastCallMillis >= System.currentTimeMillis() - 100)
                Thread.sleep(100);

            tcpResult = input.readLine();
```

When the very first line is there, the one with "setSoTimeout", the method fails with an exception.
When I do NOT set the timeout it works without a hitch.

Well.. almost I had to insert this part because if the socket was used quickly in a row it failed:

```
            if(lastCallMillis >= System.currentTimeMillis() - 100)
            Thread.sleep(100);
```

Anyway am I misunderstanding something about using java sockets or is it just horribly supported?

Comment: Do you know Connection Timeout is different then setSoTimeout? setSoTimeout will block read() call for given millisecond. if the timeout expires, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised, though the Socket is still valid.

Comment: Thanks I have set a connection timeout on the socket creation too now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want a shot read timeout don't set a short read timeout. Adding sleeps to networking code never solves anything. It is just literally a waste of time. What you should have done was added the sleep time to the timeout. But even 2.1 seconds is ludicrously short for a read timeout. Try ten, or thirty.

Comment: Strange increasing the timeout worked. I say strange because with or without the timeout the operation takes less than a second.

Comment: Err, no. If you got the timeout, the timeout period expired. If you increased the timeout and the timeout didn't happen, the timeout was too short originally.

Comment: I counted about 0.5-1 second for two operations. I'm not wrong by a factor of 4-8 and the issue from before with calling it twice in a row disappeared so something is weird, but now it works and I don't care :)